# Update() in Unity behaves oddly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have multiple instances of a prefab in Unity. Each instance have this Update():

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 retning1200 = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    Vector3 retning0130 = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, retning1200, Color.green, 1);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, retning0130, Color.green, 1);


    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, retning1200, 1))
    {
        antalNaboer++;
    }

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, retning0130, 1))
    {
        antalNaboer++;
    }

    Debug.Log("Myre i position: " + transform.position.x + " " + transform.position.y);
    Debug.Log("antal naboer :" + antalNaboer.ToString());

    antalNaboer = 0;
}
```

I expect that the code inside `Update()` will be run one time in each frame. But it seem to, that sometimes not all instances gets run. Sometimes multiple times in one frame. And the result (antal myrer) is not the same.

Myre i position: -1 0
antal naboer :2

Myre i position: -1 0
antal naboer :1

Myre i position: 1 0
antal naboer :2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

any sort of physics calculations should be checked inside the FixedUpdate Method.
As the name suggests this method will be called at a fixed time duration, so time duration between two consecutive calls is always the same unlike Update method where this may vary according to the FPS

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 retning1200 = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    Vector3 retning0130 = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, retning1200, Color.green, 1);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, retning0130, Color.green, 1);


    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, retning1200, 1))
    {
        antalNaboer++;
    }

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, retning0130, 1))
    {
        antalNaboer++;
    }

    Debug.Log("Myre i position: " + transform.position.x + " " + transform.position.y);
    Debug.Log("antal naboer :" + antalNaboer.ToString());

    antalNaboer = 0;
}
```

for more information about the differences between the two check out this link
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10993/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-fixedupdat.html